# How to use OAuth 1.0 in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, twitter, oauth, httprequest, webrequest

I'm trying to make a bot for Tumblr or Twitter, but both require OAuth requests. I'm not sure how to use a Net.WebRquest this way. I've searched all over and found very scarce information. I believe I am supposed to add some credentials in the header. This is what I have tried:

```
<pre>
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,
      $"OAuth realm=""https://api.tumblr.com/"",
      oauth_consumer_key=""{APIKEY}"",
      oauth_token=""{TOKEN}"",
      oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1"",
      oauth_signature=""?"",
      oauth_timestamp=""{(Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds}"",
      oauth_nonce=""{Now.GetHashCode()}"",
      oauth_version=""1.0""")
<pre>
```

Assuming APIKEY and TOKEN are valid, I am still getting Error 401: Unauthorized. Also, what do I put in "oauth_signature"? That did not make any sense to me. This website contained the most useful information: https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

Has anyone else here dealt with OAuth requests before, that can help me? If there were any examples out there, that would be wonderful. Thank you so much in advance.
~Nic

Comment: Are you sure it is v 1.0?  Thats pretty outdated

Comment: Yes, I am sure. How does v1.0 differ from 2.0? Or should that go in another thread?

Comment: A) Neither question belongs here. B) This is not a forum, we dont have "threads".  There are Questions and Answers, not discussion threads. C)  There is an API you can read to learn what to do/  Most site like FaceBook, ImgUR and the rest have a developer section for just this sort of thing.

Comment: True, but they are all assuming the user is using some type of library or package and can already connect using OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What jumps out at me immediately is that your parameters are not sorted alphabetically (which OAUTH requires).

Writing an OAUTH library from scratch is terrible terrible business and you should use an existing library unless you have a really good reason not to.

I am the author of [TwitterVB](https://github.com/DWRoelands/TwitterVB), a .NET library for accessing the Twitter API.  The code is hosted on GitHub and has a very permissive license.  You'll find code can classes there that will make your implementation of OAUTH much easier.

Please note that I no longer maintain this library and there are a few things that have changed about the API that interfere with its functionality.  The OAUTH pieces should all work as-is, however.

Comment: You're right, writing an OAUTH library from scratch seems like a hell that I don't want to experience. I took a look at TwitterVB which like you said, has some problems now but it is nicely done. I ended up using another library called TweetSharp which is currently being maintained.

Comment: TweetSharp is a solid library; you've chosen well.  Best of luck to you on your project!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will be sure to look at TwitterVB again to help me learn more about OAuth.